# How to get SharePoint site usage report at individual user level?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site, user, site-usage

I am trying to see if there is a way to get user-level site usage metrics for .aspx sites on SharePoint? I essentially want to see the top user of the site or site visits/time spent by each user. I know I can pull up the site usage report by clicking on the gear icon > Site Usage, but this gives overall analytics and not by each user. I went through this article, but nothing seems to work cause I don't think I have admin-level access to Office 365: [https://sharepointmaven.com/6-ways-check-sharepoint-usage-reports/#:~:text=To%20access%20it%2C%20click%20Gear,content%20(most%20popular%20content)](https://sharepointmaven.com/6-ways-check-sharepoint-usage-reports/#:%7E:text=To%20access%20it%2C%20click%20Gear,content%20(most%20popular%20content)).
Would appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 4):

Except for the M365 Audit log report, there is no data collected on a per user basis for SharePoint online. The Audit log report collects EVERYTHING about that user's activity, not just in SharePoint, so it is understandable that it is only available to admins, and it would typically only be used in security and discovery scenarios.

AFAIK, SharePoint 2010 on premises was the last version that provided site statistics with named users, but only visit counts as a total, nothing more granular. Reporting on a user's activity reveals a lot of information that has a confidential nature. I guess this is one of the reasons that this kind of data collection is no longer used or available to site owners.

So, if you have a security or discovery concern, talk to your IT folks. But other than that, you won't be able to find user based usage stats for SharePoint online.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not an admin of your tenant, then you are not able to access any usage data. It is a by-design behavior in SharePoint Online.

And the raw audit data in Admin center has access logs with all required data, so you can contact your admin and ask for the raw data. With simple data work, you can get a report with top users in that certain site.